# Angular2 strange hardcoded Object vs http.get Object issue

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, angular

I have the same JSON data, which I hold in .ts (hardcoded) and in .json (http get). Both objects look the same in development console.

I can use "{{beatlesjson | json}}" and "{{beatlesjson.paul | json}}" to printout data retrieved from external JSON, but I cant printout "{{beatlesjson.paul.name | json}}", it breaks further app execution.

Previous paragraf works as expected when using the same JSON but hardcoded in TS file.

PS. I noticed that I couldn't even print object and first sublevel if I did not initiate:  beatlesjson: Object = {};   initially. But it works only for top and first level, but breaks on second sublevel of object.

```
import {Component,ElementRef,AfterViewChecked,enableProdMode} from 'angular2/core'; enableProdMode();
import {Http, Response, RequestOptions, Headers, HTTP_PROVIDERS, HTTP_BINDINGS} from 'angular2/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `

        <pre>

        WORKS {{ beatles | json }}
        WORKS {{ beatlesjson | json }}
        <hr>

        WORKS {{ beatles.paul | json }}
        WORKS {{ beatlesjson.paul | json }}
        <hr>

        WORKS {{ beatles.paul.name | json }}
        <!-- BREAKS FURTHER EXEC, DOES NOT WORK {{ beatlesjson.paul.name | json  }} -->
        <hr>

        </pre>

    `
})

export class AppComponent {

    beatles: Object = {};
    beatlesjson: Object = {};

    constructor(http: Http){

        this.beatles = {
            john: {
                name: 'John Lennon',
                description: 'Imagining all the people',
                deceased: true
                },
            paul: {
                name: 'Paul McCartney',
                description: 'Believes in Yesterday',
                deceased: false
                },
            george: {
                name: 'George Harrison',
                description: 'His guitar gently weeps',
                deceased: true
                },
            ringo: {
                name: 'Ringo Starr',
                description: 'Going to put him in the movies',
                deceased: false
            }
        }

          http.get('app/beatles.json')
            .subscribe(
                data => { this.beatlesjson = data.json()  },
                err => console.log(err),
                () => console.log(this.beatlesjson)
            );




    }




}
```

Comment: so what errors are thrown? do you really need that filter for the `name`?

Comment: Try elvis operator as the paul property maybe null before data is loaded, `{{beatlesjson.paul?.name | json}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the Elvis operator to prevent from this behavior:

```
{{ beatlesjson?.paul?.name | json  }
```

The reason of your problem is that the data are received asynchronously through an HTTP request. So the `beatlesjson` property is undefined at the beginning.

Comment: It works now, just needed "Elvis" to make all sync up. Thank you Thierry once again ;)

Answer (score -1):

This is because the constructor body executes before the html is interpolated. so `beatles.paul` exists.

## QUICK FIX :

Instead of : `<!-- BREAKS FURTHER EXEC, DOES NOT WORK {{ beatlesjson.paul.name | json  }} -->` do:

```
{{ beatlesjson && beatlesjson.paul && beatlesjson.paul.name | json  }}
```

To ensure that you don't access a member off some `undefined` by mistake.